# Want to merge and delete duplicate rows of ms excel files

Tags: php, excel

I have suppose 10 separate .xls files. i want to merge them and also delete the duplicate rows..
can some 1 suggest me any codes for that???? is it possible to do it using php codes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for xlsx files (Office 2007+) you can do that using the excel library for PHP. See "http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel". It will allow you to open read and write xlsx files

Answer (score 1):

The simplest Way is to export the Data as [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and then Process it.

Comment: @champ - you'd have to tell us exactly what you meant by "merge and delete" for us to be able to answer this second question

Comment: I have 30 .xls files in same format.. it contains name, email id, address etc. now i want to have all the data of this 30 files together and also want if there exists any duplicate rows(it is possible to have duplicates) to be removed...